# Can't find module DBus in Xmonad 0.17

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, xmonad, ubuntu-22.04, xmonad-contrib

I am trying to install Xmonad 0.17, and I need DBus for Polybar (at least I think so)

I have followed the guide at https://xmonad.org/INSTALL.html (using stack to install), but I keep getting "Could not find module 'DBus'"

Inspired by a thread on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/pbyfw6/cant_find_module_dbus/) I have installed libghc-dbus-dev (apt) prior to stack install, but the error persist.

Is there a kind soul out there who can explain to me what is needed to install the latest version of Xmonad (including DBus!), on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04?
Preferably a step by step guide, as I know nothing about Haskell and Stack.

Many thanks in advance! :)

NB. Please don't suggest another OS - I'm working with some frameworks that require Ubuntu

Comment: Please provide a bit more context for the error message. Which module is trying to import `DBus`?

Comment: I'm trying to do the following imports:
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D